# IIS 7.5 virtual directory runtime error

Tags: c#, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, virtual-directory

I have IIS 7.5 With one web site

I added new virtual directory and getting `Runtime Error`

http://ngg-l.com/admin

I tried to added this web application as new web site and everything was ok but it does not working in virtual directory

Is there any advices?

Event viewer warning:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Admin\web.config line 49)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String sectionName)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_Identity()
   at System.Web.HttpContext.SetImpersonationEnabled()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://ngg-l.com/admin 
    Request path: /admin 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\NGG 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 13 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\NGG 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String sectionName)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_Identity()
   at System.Web.HttpContext.SetImpersonationEnabled()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Please check the Application pool in settings....

Comment: Have a look in Event Viewer, Application section, in order to see the exact error. That or set  <customErrors mode="Off"/> in your web.config so we can see the actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you need to convert the virtual directory you have added into an application.  Right click it in IIS and you should see the option to do this.